# How to set search input box on header frame in html

Tags: html, css, frame, html-frames

I have 03 frame (Header, Left_Menu and Content). In header frame I set a search input box. If anyone click on search input box then a blue color div show under the search input box but above content frame. But When I click search input box then blue color div box don’t show above content frame.

I want to create search input box as following example: 
[image]

But my search input box result show as following example:

[image]

Please, anyone can help to solve this problem.

Comment: Content of a frame can't extend beyond the frame.

Comment: is there a reason you're using 3 different frames?
could you place the different components in the same page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowadays `<frame>` is not recommended. You want to overflow your header onto the content.

This is only feasible, if you don't use frames. You should use for example a simple `<div>` HTML tag instead of the frames.

After that, you should add some CSS property, which results the desired effect. For example:

```
#header{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    heigth: 100px;
}
```

You should add the z-index property.
You can read more about z-index here: [Z-index - CSS](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/15/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/)